# Unit test with vue-utils : access to element in class

Tags: vue.js, class, testing, find

I am currently testing my view application.
**I can't seem to access the elements inside `<validation-provider>`.
Do you have any idea how to do this?**

Here is my frontend code:

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <validation-observer v-slot="{ handleSubmit }" class="flex">
            <div class="flex align-center mr-30">
                <span class="mr-10">{{ $t('time.from') }}</span>

                <validation-provider
                    class="relative"
                    v-slot="{ errors }"
                    :rules="{ requiredObject: true }">

                    <calendar-input
                        class="w-270 mr-10"
                        :class="{
                            error: errors[0]
                        }"
                        color="green"
                        multiple
                        :available-dates="{ start: activeOutlet.outlet_start_date, end: currentPrice.start_date || new Date() }"
                        v-model="date">
                    </calendar-input>

                </validation-provider>
        </validation-observer>
    </div>
</template>

<script src="./addNewPeriodLabelPrice.js"></script>
```

and my test code:

```js
describe('Unit test AddNewPeriodLabelPrice', () => {

    it("validation-observer should exist", () => {
        const wrapper = mount(AddNewPeriodLabelPrice);
        expect(wrapper.find('validation-observer').exists()).toBe(true);
    })

    it("span should exist", () => {
        const wrapper = mount(AddNewPeriodLabelPrice);
        expect(wrapper.find('#test-span').exists()).toBe(true);
    })
    // Error: expect true but received false
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: `validation-observer` doesn't render any elements, so you wouldn't be able to `wrapper.find()` it. And there's no element with the `test-span` ID in your markup, so that wouldn't be found either.

Comment: Ok thanks. So, how can I test the text in <span> ?